# SQL - Year Over Year Calculation Using First & Next Records

Tags: sql

I am using this server to test:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all

Question:

I am looking to calculate year over year growth in a new column called 'YOY' using cast function in absolute value with one query.

```
SELECT Orders.EmployeeID, Year(Orders.OrderDate) AS 'Year', COUNT(Year(Orders.OrderDate)) AS '# of Orders', 'CAL' AS 'YOY'
FROM Orders
WHERE Orders.EmployeeID = 4 OR Orders.EmployeeID = 3 OR Orders.EmployeeID = 1
GROUP BY Year(Orders.OrderDate), Orders.EmployeeId
ORDER BY Orders.EmployeeId DESC
```

Output:

```
  EmployeeID    'Year'  '# of Orders'   'YOY'
  4              1996       31           CAL 
  4              1997       9            CAL
  3              1996       18           CAL
  3              1997       13           CAL
  1              1996       26           CAL
  1              1997       3            CAL
```

[image: Here Is How It Looks So Far]
Expected Output:

```
  EmployeeID    'Year'  '# of Orders'   'YOY'
  4              1996       31           70% 
  4              1997       9            
  3              1996       18           28%
  3              1997       13           
  1              1996       26           88%
  1              1997       3
```

Comment: show me row samples from orders and expected output

Comment: Hey Bhavesh, ADDED - THX!

Comment: Added: Output & Expected Output - Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following:
**Edited Query:**

```
select oagg1.EmployeeID,oagg1.yr,oagg1.cnt,oagg2.cnt next_yr_qty,
        (((oagg1.cnt-oagg2.cnt)*100)/oagg1.cnt ) yoy
from (SELECT EmployeeID,substr(orderDate,1,4)yr,count(*) cnt
        FROM [Orders] o
        where EmployeeID in (1,3,4)
        group by EmployeeID,substr(orderDate,1,4))oagg1
left outer join         
    (SELECT EmployeeID,substr(orderDate,1,4)yr,count(*) cnt
        FROM [Orders] o
    where EmployeeID in (1,3,4)
    group by EmployeeID,substr(orderDate,1,4))oagg2
on oagg1.EmployeeID=oagg2.EmployeeID
and cast(oagg1.yr as int)=cast(oagg2.yr as int)-1
order by 1 desc
```

Basically you just need to self-join orders table to pick last year's number of orders.

Comment: Hey Bhavesh, much appreciate your help! but for some reason it does not run? What about absolute value in % Thank You!

Comment: Thank You So Much Bhavesh! Have Been Trying To Achieve This For The Past Week With No Luck. Here You Come & The Problem Is Solved. Absolute Asset :)